# Construct sigma-algebra ( sigma-field)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, statistics

i'm studying mathematical statistics, with hogg,

while constructing sigma-field generated by $D$, where $D$={C,D,E,F}

i don't know what is sigma-filed generated by $D$.

let's say universal set $X$ and sigma-fields could be a collection of subset of $X$.

i know what is sigma-field and what we need to confirm that it is sigma-field.

but when think about the smallest sigma-field containg $D$, i'm curious that how third condition of sigma - field can be used.(closed under countable union)

if we say the smallest sigma field containing $D$ is $\beta$ and i know $\beta$ has {C,D,E,F,cC,cD,cE,cF,X,cX} and what else?

i mean that is only C$\bigcup$D$\bigcup$E$\bigcup$F in $\beta$  ? or  is C$\bigcup$D$\bigcup$E also in $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\Omega = \{C,D,E,F\}$, with each of these being subsets of some universal set $X$,  $\beta$ the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\Omega$. Since you know $\beta$ needs to include the empty set, the whole space $X$, $\{C,D,E,F,C^c,D^c,E^c,F^c\}$, and needs to be closed under countable unions, intersections, and complements, then the following must also be included (with the understanding that any duplicate elements only appear once each):

pairwise unions:
$$\{C\cup D, C\cup D^c, C^c\cup D, C^c\cup D^c, C\cup E, C\cup E^c, C^c\cup E, C^c\cup E^c, C\cup F,C\cup F^c, C^c\cup F,C^c\cup F^c,D\cup E,D\cup E^c,D^c\cup E,D^c\cup E^c, D\cup F,D\cup F^c, D^c\cup F,D^c\cup F^c, E\cup F,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E\cup F^c,E^c\cup F, E^c\cup F^c\}$$
and the complements of each of these:
$$\{C^c\cap D^c, C^c\cap D, C\cap D^c, C\cap D, C^c\cap E^c, C^c\cap E, C\cap E^c, C\cap E, C^c\cap F^c,C^c\cap F,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C\cap F^c,C\cap F,D^c\cap E^c,D^c\cap E,D\cap E^c,D\cap E, D^c\cap F^c,D^c\cap F, D\cap F^c,D\cap F,\ \ E^c\cap F^c, E^c\cap F,E\cap F^c, E\cap F\}$$
(Unless I have missed some elements, this would take care of both the pairwise intersections and pairwise unions)

You have to then repeat the process for triplet unions, e.g. (not intended to be an exhaustive list): 
$$\{C\cup D\cup E,C^c\cup D\cup E, C\cup D^c\cup E, C\cup D\cup E^c, C^c\cup D^c\cup E, C^c\cup D\cup E^c, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C\cup D^c\cup E^c, C^c\cup D^c\cup E^c\},$$

their complements, e.g. (respective to those listed above, again noting this is not intended to be an exhaustive list)
$$\{C^c\cap D^c\cap E^c,C\cap D^c\cap E^c, C^c\cap D\cap E^c, C^c\cap D^c\cap E, C\cap D\cap E^c, C\cap D^c\cap E, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C^c\cap D\cap E, C\cap D\cap E\},$$
and then also include all of the possible four-set unions, intersections, and their complements. (In principle, you would need to also include five-, six-, seven-, and eight-set unions, intersections, and their complements, but these are going to be either empty or already included in the list you would produce through the others)

It also needs to include things like $C\cup (D\cap E)$, $(C\cup D\cup E)\cap F$, and so on (in other words, subsets involving 3 sets with one union and one intersection, subsets involving 4 sets with one union and two intersections, two unions and one intersection, and so on, being sure to also include their complements).

In addition, it also needs to contain intersections of these, unions of these, their complements, intersections of unions, unions of intersections, intersections of intersections, unions of unions, and so on (at each step omitting any that have already been listed). Since $\Omega$ is fairly small (being only 4 sets), it seems likely that you would eventually reach a point where this process would become a matter of listing things you've already written down (hence, you would eventually write out every single element of the sigma-algebra), though I am not going to attempt to do so (nor do I necessarily suggest it, as it wouldn't tell you anything that the axioms of the definition aren't already telling you).

This is certainly not intended to provide an exhaustive list of every set that must be included in the sigma-algebra (there are 24 pairwise unions and 24 pairwise intersections, which are incidentally also the complements of the pairwise unions), but this hopefully gives you an idea of what would be required if you wanted to explicitly construct the sigma-algebra.

---

By the way, I apologize ahead of time for any typos (I'd be very surprised if I didn't make at least one), and if you need clarification beyond this, please ask. This isn't necessarily a conceptual description of the sigma-algebra, as much as it is a starting point for the explicit construction of it.